# React useEffect hook register callback with access to state

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks

I´m creating a new instacne of a map component in the useEffect hook with second parameter [] so it only runs once.

After creating the instance I want to register a callback, which is fired if the user interacts with the map. Inside this callback I want to access the state of my component. How can I do this, without causing a loop? If I don´t add my state to the second parameter the state stays the same with every run of the callback (as expected), but if I add it, I cause a loop.

```
export const Map = (props: any) => {
const [state, setState]: [MapState, any] = useGlobalState({
    id: 'MAP',
    initialValue: getInitialValue(initialized),
});

useEffect(() => {
    mapInstance = new mapFramework.Map(});
    mapInstance.on('move', () => {
        console.log(state);
    });
}, []);
}
```

Comment: probably because your state is an object. do you care about everything in the `state` object or some particular properties? If its particular properties, you can pass only those properties

Comment: Yes, have to access the whole object, but it only contains three props, so don´t think this is the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `useRef`

```
export const Map = (props: any) => {
const [state, setState]: [MapState, any] = useGlobalState({
    id: 'MAP',
    initialValue: getInitialValue(initialized),
});
const stateRef = useRef(state)

useEffect(()=>{
    stateRef.current = state
}, [state])

useEffect(() => {
    mapInstance = new mapFramework.Map(});
    mapInstance.on('move', () => {
        console.log(stateRef.current)
    });
}, []);
}
```